# How to get the row size and the column of an array in common lisp?

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to create a simple chess engine in lisp for fun in my free  time. This is my design.

```
57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
```

I looked at more  complicated solutions but i came out with what i believe is the simplest one. Say the bishop is on the square 23, it could move 4 possible moves, (to  16 or 14 or 32 or 30), so  it moves -7 or +7 or +9 or -9.

I create an array

```
(make-array '(8 8)
            :initial-contents
            '((R B N Q K B N R)
              (P P P P P P P P)
              (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
              (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
              (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
              (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
              (P P P P P P P P)
              (R B N Q K B N R)))
```

And move the pieces from index to index. But i need to get the row size and the column size to do `for bishop >= row && array size, move to x` if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the number of rows and columns in the array, try `ARRAY-DIMENSION`

```
(setq a (make-array '(8 8) :initial-contents
'((R B N Q K B N R)
 (P P P P P P P P)
(NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
(NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
(NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
(NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
          (P P P P P P P P)
          (R B N Q K B N R))))
```

Now:

```
(array-rank a)
```

=> `2`

```
(array-dimension a 0)
```

=> `8`

```
(array-dimension a 1)
```

=> `8`

Also, because you seem to be trying to access the array both by row/column combination and by a flat index, a *displaced* array may be useful:

```
(setq b (make-array '(64) :displaced-to a))
```

=> `#(R B N Q K B N R P P P P P P P P NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL
  NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL
  NIL NIL P P P P P P P P R B N Q K B N R)`

This is basically a one-dimensional view of the two-dimensional array. The underlying data is the same; changes to one will change the other.

```
(setf (aref a 1 1) nil)
(aref b 9)
```

=> `nil`

Comment: the displacement does not look correct. You make an `(8 8)` array and get a vector?

Comment: @RainerJoswig, You're right, that was a copy/paste error.  Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

```
CL-USER 51 > (setq *board*
                   (make-array '(8 8) :initial-contents
                               '((R B N Q K B N R)
                                 (P P P P P P P P)
                                 (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
                                 (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
                                 (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
                                 (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
                                 (P P P P P P P P)
                                 (R B N Q K B N R))))
#2A((R B N Q K B N R)
    (P P P P P P P P)
    (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
    (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
    (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
    (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
    (P P P P P P P P)
    (R B N Q K B N R))
```

You can now access this 2d array with a one index in row-major order by using `ROW-MAJOR-AREF`:

```
CL-USER 52 > (loop for i below 64 collect (row-major-aref *board* i))
(R
 B
 N
 Q
 K
 B
 N
 R
 P
 P
 P
 P
 P
 P
 P
 P
 ...)
```

Alternatively you can set up a one-dimensional displaced array.

Answer (score 3):

```
? (defparameter *y* (make-array '(4 8)))
*Y*

? (array-dimensions *y*)  ;;; the array's dimensions
(4 8)

? (array-rank *y*)        ;;; the number of dimensions
2
? (array-dimension *y* 0) ;;; dimension 0
4
? (array-dimension *y* 1) ;;; dimension 1
8
```

More details [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node160.html).